# Viewing mapped network drive on remote windown machine using Java

Tags: java, winforms, swing, winapi, apache-commons

Scenario:
Client(from where we are viewing the filesystem of the server): Windows 7.

Server(where a network drive 'Z:' is mapped ) : Windows Server 2008.

Requirement:
Any method by which we are able to view System drives(C:,D:,etc) as well as mapped network drives(Z:) on server.
We are running the application on Client.Hence Scenario is this application should be able to browse Server's System drives(i.e C:,D:,E:) as well as the networked drive mapped on server (i.e Z:).

Currently we are using JFileChooser but it is listing out only System drives and not networked drives.
Is there any API using which I can view System as well as Mapped network drives.

Comment: It appears JFileChooser has rather poor support for networked drives. I'm not a Java guy, nor do I have any network drives to test with, but I see [there are several JFileChooser alternatives](https://www.google.com/search?q=JFileChooser+doesn't+show+network+drives), or if need be (and if portability is not an issue), you could call the Windows API `GetOpenFileName()` and `GetSaveFileName()` functions (or if you're feeling *really* adventurous and don't want XP support, the Common Item Dialog), which should have network options. Hope that helps, anyway...

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I will check and update it asap on weather it is fulfilling my requirement.